# Is System.Dns available on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to build a Windows Phone project that I've ported some code into from another project.

The only error I have is on the line

```
ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry(address).AddressList[0], port);

"the name 'Dns' does not exist in the current context"
```

Should this type be available in Windows Phone?

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page I can see that Dns exists within System.Net, but I can't see Dns in my project inside the System.Net namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. The first column of the table shows where this member would be available. The following image is from the String class. There you see that this constructor is available for

- XNA Framework
- Portable Class Library
- Windows Store Apps

[image: Availability of Member]

Comment: Where did you get this information, so that I might view it myself?

Comment: This information is from the System.String class. If you compare this image with the information in the System.Net.Dns (the link you provided) class you will see that there will be differences in the number of images.

Comment: Ok, I get you! Thanks.